# What does footprint_cartridge_conf.xml actually do?

Tags: ambient-data-framework, session-preview

The [docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3C70F892-69F4-4FEE-922D-39F1AFEBD539) [login required] state that your web application cd_ambient_conf.xml should contain the following cartridges when setting up Session Preview:

```
<Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
<Cartridge File="footprint_cartridge_conf.xml"/>
```

Firstly, is that a typo with the first cartridge? We are using `session_cartridge_conf.xml` and it works fine. **UPDATE:** I see that session_cartridge_conf.xml is for SmartTarget, so ignore this.

Secondly, what do these cartridges actually do? I can't find it described anywhere in the docs. I had assumed that the footprint cartridge overrides values in the ADF from Footprints sent by XPM, however we do not have this configured, yet Footprints seem to work just fine.

Answer (score 6):

The preview cartridge (cd_preview_ambient.jar) manages your sessions -- ensuring that you have a valid token that hasn't expired, creating a new sessions as necessary, etc.

The footprint cartridge just adds some standard claims about the session. I think this one is mostly there for backwards-compatibility and to provide some claims out-of-the-box for the Footprint functionality in Experience Manager. In case you are wondering, it's part of the cd_preview_web.jar file; there is no footprint_cartridge.jar file anymore.

Comment: OK - that makes more sense. What bit of all this actually overrides ADF claims with the values from the footprint then?

Comment: The PreviewClaimStore does the actual overwriting of claim values based on the footprint cookie(s) sent in the request.